# higher order skill of packages in Java

Tags: java, hierarchy

Is there a definition for parent of a package in Java ? If so, why are/aren't we using packages as a most super parents? Because we have `methods/classes/packages`... and I think there is something that could not have used them as making the most of them. And lastly, is there a path for put all things into a package-wise thing?(I mean, very big package). If yes, why would people need it? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: no, in Java there are no hierarchies/relationship between packages , even for nested packages.

Comment: > Is there a definition for parent of a package in Java? No. > If so Not.

Comment: You've asked a few subjective questions here .. can you narrow it down to something more objective? If so, please flag this for moderator review.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use child-parent relationship with inheritance (super and subclasses).  Packages are rather a way of ordering your project.  We aren't using them as most super parents because it is much easier to achieve that with classes and subclasses.  Well you could say that when you import a package you are going to extend some of its classes and in this way it would be "most super parent".  You can put everything in one very big package, but you lose point of working with packages that is ordering your project.